# Migrate Java Option call to kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-interop

I'm taking my first steps with kotlin.

I am migrating some my existing java code to kotlin.

I have the folllowing line:

```
storyDate.ifPresent(article::setPublishDate);
```

Where storyDate is an Optional and article has a method setPublishDate(Date) method.

How would I migrate this line to kotlin?

The auto migrator at https://try.kotlinlang.org is

```
storyDate.ifPresent(Consumer<Date>({ article.setPublishDate() }))
```

But this line doesn't compile with the kotlin compiler.

Comment: The choice for you is, do you want idiomatic Kotlin code that uses the built-in way of dealing with null safety or do you want to stick with more Java friendly code that must resort to optionals to hide the null checks

Comment: You don't even have to convert it. The Java line should work as well. It's compatible with Kotlin syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs... I've realised, as you've all said, that null safety is built into kotlin so converting java code that uses lots of Optionals would require some massaging to I would say, remove the Optional as one should be using a language as its designed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It’s rather uncommon to use `Optional` in Kotlin. If you can make `storyDate` work as an ordinary unwrapped type, such constructs can often be expressed with a simple `let` call:

```
storyDate?.let {
    article.setPublishDate(it) 
    //probably property access works as well:
    article.publishDate = it
}
```

How it works: The safe call `?.` will invoke `let` only if `storyDate` is not `null`, otherwise the whole expression evaluates to, again, `null`. When the variable is not `null`, `let` is called with a simple lambda where `storyDate` is accessible by `it` (or you can rename it to whatever you like).

**Side note:**

If `storyDate` really must be `Optional`, you can still use the depicted construct by unwrapping it like this:

```
storyDate.orElse(null)?.let {}
```

Comment: I'm not very sure `let` would work on an `Optional` (or at least, it would not give the desired effect).

Comment: Given it’s not an optional in Kotlin, I’ll make it clear

Answer (score 10):

I strongly prefer using extension functions and extension fields, so I've written smth like

```
val <T> Optional<T>.value: T?
    get() = orElse(null)
```

And then you can use it anywhere (after import) like

```
myOptional.value?.let {
    // handle here
}
```

Comment: extension functions are certainly new to me... and a bit foreign for a java dev

Comment: @MichaelWiles well, new language — new paradigms…

Answer (score 6):

```
storyDate.ifPresent { Article.setPublishDate(it) }
```

or

```
storyDate.ifPresent(Article::setPublishDate)
```

will work.

In the first example, `it` denotes the value in the optional instance, which is the `Date` in the optional `storyDate`.

I assumed that `Article` is a class, which has the `setPublishDate(Date)` static method, because class names are always capitalized.

---

But if `article` is an instance, not a class, and it has non-static method, then the following will work.

```
// article = Article(/* some Article-typed object */)
storyDate.ifPresent { article.setPublishDate(it) }
```

`it` has the same meaning as the above one, i.e., the actual `Date` value in `Optional`.

Comment: you wrote it as if it was a static method, which obviously it isn't.